# What hardware specs are important when looking for a laptop that can quickly switch monitors?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hardware-rec

During the day I often connect/disconnect my laptop to external displays, projectors and docking stations through HDMI. After switching the monitor the computer needs time to reorder/redraw the windows, I am looking to minimize that time.

As I am looking for a new laptop I wonder what (if any) factors would play a role in reducing the time needed for the laptop to be usable after a monitor switch.
Factors that come to mind are:

- Integrated vs dedicated GPU
- GPU memory
- OS
- Processor speed
- Video interface(HDMI, DisplayPort, etc...)

Please note I am not asking for a product recommendation (which will soon be outdated), but rather for factors that should keep the switch time to a minimum (which are probably more stable in time).

Comment: Its more likely going to be a delay in the external display(s) than something on your laptop. I would therefor look into a way for minimizing the amount of times you switch between using and not using a monitor.

Comment: Why don’t we start with what you are having issues with now? What make and model of computer? I don’t agree with the statement suggesting that it is typical to take 1 minute to be able to use the computer again after changing monitors. I do this often and have done it for years with multiple different laptops and configurations. It’s never been a significant factor for me. So the first answer that comes to mind is ANY computer other than the one you are using now should solve the problem.

Comment: I haven't used a machine in the last 5 years that took more than 1-2 seconds to detect a display and a couple more to extend the desktop to it. It sounds like your machine is worryingly underpowered and without knowing your current specs it is hard to say exactly what is causing it. I agree with Appleoddity, any current generation machine above bargain basement price *should* do this easily.

Comment: I surely can add the specs I of the machines that can take *up to* a minute to rearrange themselves. But that would make the question very specific. Why can't we focus on what hardware helps to minimize this switch time, without focusing too much on the current value of that time?

Answer (score 1):

It is very uncommon to have more than five seconds for the switching.

What OS do you use?
When the layout changes, under Windows, each open program gets a WM_RESIZE (and probably WM_DRAW) message sent, and if there are one or more programs that are badly coded, and take a long time to rearrange/redraw their window content, there is nothing much you can do to speed it up.
Other OS are probably similar.

Try the change with nothing open. Is it faster/fast enough? Then try with each of your programs open. You should be able to identify the bad one(s).
Solutions are to not use them, or get a more powerful machine, so whatever silly things they do runs faster. This would *probably* be dependant on CPU and maybe memory.

Comment: I've followed your steps and could pinpoint the slow transition to the Microsoft Office suite and Total Commander. Can't really stay away from those as I need those for my daily work. So, that leaves your second suggestion `get a more powerful machine`. That is my initial question. Could you elaborate on that? Is it higher CPU clock or more cores? Is it faster or more RAM?